# Apache2 mod_proxy_fcgi ProxyFCGISetEnvIf Directory Specific Override

Tags: apache, apache2, fastcgi

Does anyone know if you can override a ProxyFCGISetEnvIf directive in a directory section?  The documentation for apache's mod_proxy_fcgi says it is valid in a  section, but I'm not seeing the ProxyFCGISetEnvIf apply when in the directory.

Here's an example:

```
<VirtualHost *:443>
    ServerName  test7.com
    ServerAlias  

    DocumentRoot /var/www/test

    ProxyPassMatch ^(.*\.php)$ fcgi://127.0.0.1:9001/var/www/test/$1
    ProxyFCGISetEnvIf "true" PHP_ADMIN_VALUE "open_basedir=/var/www/test:/usr/share/php:/usr/share/pear \n upload_tmp_dir=/tmp; \n session.save_path=/var/www/php_sessions;"

    <Directory "/var/www/test/cooldir">
         ProxyFCGISetEnvIf "true" PHP_ADMIN_VALUE "open_basedir=/var/www/test:/var/www:/usr/share/php:/usr/share/pear \n upload_tmp_dir=/tmp; \n session.save_path=/var/www/php_sessions;"
    </Directory>

    SSLEngine on
    SSLCertificateFile /etc/letsencrypt/live/test7.com/fullchain.pem
    SSLCertificateKeyFile /etc/letsencrypt/live/test7.com/privkey.pem

</VirtualHost>
```

When I'm in the "cooldir" directory, phpinfo() is showing the that the open_basedir variable value did not change.  So, what's the hierarchy for ProxyFCGISetEnvIf values in mod_proxy_fcgi?  I would imagine it should work like nginx with specific directory declarations overriding the top level.  For example, in nginx, this works:

```
location /cooldir {
    root /var/www/test/;
    index index.php index.html index.htm;

    location ~ ^/cooldir/(.+\.php)$ {
        try_files $uri =404;
        root /var/www/test/;
        fastcgi_pass 127.0.0.1:9001;
        fastcgi_index index.php;
        fastcgi_param SCRIPT_FILENAME $request_filename;
        fastcgi_param  PHP_ADMIN_VALUE "open_basedir=/var/www:/tmp:/usr/share:/var/www/php_sessions \n upload_tmp_dir=/tmp \n session.save_path=/var/www/php_sessions";
        include /etc/nginx/fastcgi_params;
        limit_req zone=one burst=5;
    }
}
```

Any help is appreciated.

Comment: Hi all.

I have noticed something strange with the ProxyFCGISetEnvIf directive. Values seems to be shared across Apache virtual hosts within the same PHP-FPM pool. If a vhost define a value (e.g. open_basedir) with this directive and a second vhost doesn't, the second vhost inherit the open_basedir value of the first vhost. I have to explicitly define the open_basedir in all vhosts. 

This is not a problem, but if values are shared, is there a risk PHP-FPM mix wrong values when two or more request of different vhosts are processed simultaneouly ?

Comment: @David I think this is by default the way it works.  nginx configurations do the same thing when using php-fpm proxy.

Answer (score 1):

You have to use a `<Location>` directive instead of a `<Directory>` directive according to a response I received on the apache users mailing list:

```
<Location "/webmail">
        ProxyFCGISetEnvIf "true" PHP_ADMIN_VALUE "open_basedir=/var/lib/roundcube:/etc/roundcube:/usr/share:/tmp:/var/www/php_sessions:/var/log/roundcube; \n upload_tmp_dir=/tmp; \n session.save_path=/var/www/php_sessions;"
</Location>
```